# Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 failed

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

I've a problem. Upgrade failed after "Setting new software channels", when Calculating changes.
I tried error:

```
Not all updates can be installed

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade:
E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

 This can be caused by:
 * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.
```

Now i have 1580 packages to update and do not update. Partial system upgrade also fails in the first step. What next? Alternatively, to undo the changes? Thank's to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

- -sudo apt-get update -f ,   sudo apt-get -f install

or

- sudo apt-get install aptitude  , sudo aptitude safe-upgrade

---

Also you can fix broken packages via synaptic ,it is in otion menu just read carefully what is in 'delete' category cause you can mess up whole system and delete everything